# Using VBA to navigate a href in IE HTML document

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am trying to use VBA to navigate IE to search some of the information for me. However, after the code is written and I run it. I found everything is fine before the part of clicking href, but if I use "F8" to execute the code one by one and it works. Unfortunately, I haven't found some situation like mine in this forum. Can someone give some hints to me? Thanks

```
Sub GetData()
    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLAllhref As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

    studentid = 12345678

    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "https://xxx.xxx"

    Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

    Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document
    Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("abcd")
    HTMLInput.Focus
    HTMLInput.FireEvent("onchange")
    HTMLInput.Value = studentid

    Set HTMLButton = HTMLDoc.getElementById("submit")
    HTMLButton.Click
```

The part above works properly, but the following part works only if I use "F8" to execute one by one

```
    Set HTMLAllhref = HTMLDoc.GetElementsByTagName ("a")
    For Each link in HTMLAllhref
        If InStr(link.innerText, studentid) Then
            IE.Navigate link.href
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What error message are you getting when fails and on which line?

Comment: Hi QHarr, thanks for your prompt support. I received no error message from the vba. The IE  just seems stop at HTMLButton.Click and the second part of code takes no effects.

Comment: See initial suggestions below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If works with F8 it is usually a timing issue and you need to determine where a wait needs to happen.

As a minimum be sure to use a proper wait after each `.Navigate2`, `.Click` and `.Submit` to allow for page loading:

```
While IE.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
```

Potentially also after:

```
HTMLInput.FireEvent("onchange")
```

2) The recommended method is `.navigate2`, not `.navigate`.